# Custom Compile in Texstudio with "%" not as Jobname

Tags: texstudio

I have a simple question, for which I just don't find any awnser. I run a custom command after the compilation of the pdf in texstudio to generate multiple svg(s) out of it:

```
pdf2svg %.pdf output-page%d.svg all
```

However, texstudio recognizes the second `%` as the "jobname", so that it does not serve as placeholder for the numbering in the resulting svgs. How do I "tell" texstudio that the second `%` is actually that sign and not "jobname"?

Would be happy about any help!

Comment: Try this: `pdf2svg %.pdf output-page%%d.svg all`

Comment: Fantastic that's it! Thank you so much.

Comment: See TeXstudio User manual, 4.4 External Commands

Comment: @hair-splitter if you want you can extend your comment into an answer (maybe with an explicit quote from the manual) so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the TeXstudio User manual:

> TeXstudio implements some of its features as external commands which
> can be set up in the config dialog ("Options/Configure TeXstudio" ->
> "Commands").
>
> Before an external command is executed the command line undergoes
> expansion where the following tokens are recognized and replaced by
> TeXstudio:
>
> % is replaced by the absolute pathname of the root (master) document
> up to but excluding the file extension.
>
> %% is replaced by the % symbol.

So the next command works:
`pdf2svg %.pdf output-page%%d.svg all`